# Show alert dialog on onCreateView() of fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to android development. From my activity.java file, I am checking if create_task menu item is clicked. If it is clicked, i want to show a pop up screen create_task(layout in xml).

activity.java

```
case R.id.create_task:
CreateTaskFragment createTaskFragment = new CreateTaskFragment();
                FragmentTransaction createTaskft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                createTaskft.replace(R.id.flContent, createTaskFragment);
                createTaskft.commit();
```

CreateTaskFragment.java

```
public class CreateTaskFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_task, container, false);
        AlertDialog newTaskdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setView(view)
                .create();
        newTaskdialog.show();
        newTaskdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        return view;
    }

}
```

I get this error when i run it currently:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
> on the child's parent first.

Comment: this is probably going to get closed as some sort of duplicate, but do research on [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs), i think that's what you're essentially trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                getActivity()).create();

        alertDialog1.setTitle("Alert Dialog");
        alertDialog1.setMessage("this is alert dialog box");
        alertDialog1.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
        alertDialog1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        alertDialog1.show();
```